# mysql start works but mysqladmin is giving error

Tags: mysql

I deleted mysql from ubuntu 18.04. Now I am trying to install again. I tried the command:

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-client-core-5.7
```

The above command worked and ended with:

> Preparing to unpack
> .../mysql-client-core-5.7_5.7.35-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
> Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.35-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over
> (5.7.34-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ... Setting up mysql-client-core-5.7
> (5.7.35-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ... Processing triggers for man-db
> (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) …

But when I tried to install

```
@lc2530hz:~$ sudo apt install mariadb-client-core-10.1
```

I got following messages:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> mariadb-client-core-10.1 : Conflicts: mysql-client-5.7 but 5.7.35-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
> mysql-client-5.7 : Depends: mysql-client-core-5.7 but it is not going to be installed
> E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

However, sql start command executed:

```
@lc2530hz:~$ mysql server start
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.35, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
```

But I can’t create the password:

```
zulfi@lc2530hz:~$ mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

> Command 'mysqladmin' not found, but can be installed with:
>
> sudo apt install mysql-client-5.7    sudo apt install
> mariadb-client-10.1

At this stage what should I do? Is mysql installed on my system? Somebody please guide me

Comment: As unhelpful as this comment will be, experience says that a mess has been created. When both MySQL and MariaDB tools are installed on the same system, a terrible tangle of a mess is created and it’s very difficult to completely undo. How invested are you in the installation?

Comment: MariaDB did not install so I don't have the mess but what about the mysqladmin? how can I install it?